# Uploading Multiple Images to Imgur API with Ruby is Slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, image-uploading, imgur

So I have a form that can submit multiple images at once. I also wrote a wrapper for the Imgur API in Ruby. My problem is that since this happens completely synchronously, it takes forever and times out for even 10 images. I'm wondering if there is a better way that would be able to handle more images.

All I can think of is asynchronously submitting forms with one image each, but I'm not sure if that's a good idea or if it will just hold up other requests.

```
class MissionsController < ApplicationController
  def add_images
    image_ids = params[:images].collect do |image|
      Image.with_imgur(
        title: "#{@mission.trip.name} - #{current_user.username}",
        image: image,
        album_id: @mission.album.imgur_id,
        user_id: current_user.id,
        trip_id: @mission.trip_id
      ).imgur_id
    end
  end
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.with_imgur(options)
    trip_id = options.delete(:trip_id)
    user_id = options.delete(:user_id)
    image = Imgur::Image.create(options)
    create(
      imgur_id: image["id"],
      link: image["link"],
      trip_id: trip_id,
      user_id: user_id
    )
  end
end
```

https://github.com/tomprats/toms-missions/blob/master/app/models/imgur.rb#L116

```
class Imgur::Image < Base
  def self.create(options)
    url = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image"
    params = {
      image: options[:image],
      album: options[:album_id],
      type: options[:type] || "file", # "file" || "base64" || "URL"
      title: options[:title],
      description: options[:description]
    }
    api_post(url, params).body["data"]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at Typhoeus https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus - I've used this in the past to handle uploads etc to Amazon Glacier. I found that it could be much faster - Typhoeus gives you a future object and will handle the upload of you in the background without blocking the application.

I hope this helps!